# Generate random array of floats between a range

Tags: python, arrays, random, numpy

I haven't been able to find a function to generate an array of random floats of a given length between a certain range.

I've looked at [Random sampling](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) but no function seems to do what I need.

[random.uniform](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) comes close but it only returns a single element, not a specific number.

This is what I'm after:

```
ran_floats = some_function(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=50)
```

which would return an array of 50 random non-unique floats (ie: repetitions are allowed) uniformly distributed in the range `[0.5, 13.3]`.

Is there such a function?

Comment: You've tagged the question `numpy`, but you didn't mention `numpy.random.uniform`, even though it has exactly the call signature you want.  Do you have the `numpy` library available?

Comment: `[random.uniform(low, high) for i in xrange(size)]`

Comment: @DSM yes I have and you are apparently 100% correct. I missed that function and it appears to do exactly what I need. Would you mind presenting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

[`np.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) fits your use case:

```
sampl = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(50,))
```

**Update Oct 2019:**

While the syntax is still supported, it looks like the API changed with NumPy 1.17 to support greater control over the random number generator. Going forward the API has changed and you should look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.uniform.html

The enhancement proposal is here: https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.html

Comment: OP's intuitive search question is `some_function(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=50)`. That's how well python libs are designed #wow

Comment: Size was not completely clear and link does not work. Here is a minor clarification.         
**size:** int or tuple of ints, optional. Output shape. If the given shape is, e.g., (m, n, k), then m * n * k samples are drawn. If size is None default), a single value is returned if low and high are both scalars.

Comment: @vlad - thanks for pointing out the issue with the link. I've updated the answer to hopefully cover the current usage.

Comment: In the official documentation of Numpy, the following function resolves the problem.  
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html

Answer (score 31):

Why not use a list comprehension?

In Python 2

```
ran_floats = [random.uniform(low,high) for _ in xrange(size)]
```

In Python 3, `range` works like `xrange`([ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-vs-xrange-python/))

```
ran_floats = [random.uniform(low,high) for _ in range(size)]
```

Answer (score 11):

This is the simplest way

```
np.random.uniform(start,stop,(rows,columns))
```

Answer (score 7):

There may already be a function to do what you're looking for, but I don't know about it (yet?).
In the meantime, I would suggess using:

```
ran_floats = numpy.random.rand(50) * (13.3-0.5) + 0.5
```

This will produce an array of shape (50,) with a uniform distribution between 0.5 and 13.3.

You could also define a function:

```
def random_uniform_range(shape=[1,],low=0,high=1):
    """
    Random uniform range

    Produces a random uniform distribution of specified shape, with arbitrary max and
    min values. Default shape is [1], and default range is [0,1].
    """
    return numpy.random.rand(shape) * (high - min) + min
```

**EDIT**: Hmm, yeah, so I missed it, there is numpy.random.uniform() with the same exact call you want!
Try `import numpy; help(numpy.random.uniform)` for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could use [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html)

```
from scipy import stats
stats.uniform(0.5, 13.3).rvs(50)
```

and for the record to sample integers it's

```
stats.randint(10, 20).rvs(50)
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not to combine [random.uniform](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) with a list comprehension?

```
>>> def random_floats(low, high, size):
...    return [random.uniform(low, high) for _ in xrange(size)]
... 
>>> random_floats(0.5, 2.8, 5)
[2.366910411506704, 1.878800401620107, 1.0145196974227986, 2.332600336488709, 1.945869474662082]
```

Answer (score 4):

The for loop in list comprehension takes time and makes it slow.
It is better to use numpy parameters (low, high, size, ..etc)

```
import numpy as np
import time
rang = 10000
tic = time.time()
for i in range(rang):
    sampl = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=2, size=(182))
print("it took: ", time.time() - tic)

tic = time.time()
for i in range(rang):
    ran_floats = [np.random.uniform(0,2) for _ in range(182)]
print("it took: ", time.time() - tic)
```

sample output:

('it took: ', 0.06406784057617188)

('it took: ', 1.7253198623657227)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are OK with a list of real numbers instead, you can use the standard `random.randrange`:

```
def some_function(low, high, size):
    low_int = int(low * 1000)
    high_int = int(high *1000)
    return [random.randrange(low_int, high_int, size)/1000 for _ in range(size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.random_sample(size)` will generate random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your example

```
sample = (np.random.random([50, ]) * 13.3) - 0.5
```