# Generate 'n' unique random numbers within a range

Tags: python, random, unique

I know how to generate a random number within a range in Python.

```
random.randint(numLow, numHigh)
```

And I know I can put this in a loop to generate n amount of these numbers

```
for x in range (0, n):
    listOfNumbers.append(random.randint(numLow, numHigh))
```

However, I need to make sure each number in that list is unique. Other than a load of conditional statements, is there a straightforward way of generating n number of unique random numbers?

The important thing is that each number in the list is different to the others..

So

[12, 5, 6, 1] = good

But

[12, 5, 5, 1] = bad, because the number 5 occurs twice.

Comment: Take a look: [Create random list of integers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172131/create-random-list-of-integers-in-python).

Answer (score 584, accepted):

If you just need sampling without replacement:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(1, 100), 3)
[77, 52, 45]
```

[random.sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) takes a population and a sample size `k` and returns `k` random members of the population.

If you have to control for the case where `k` is larger than `len(population)`, you need to be prepared to catch a `ValueError`:

```
>>> try:
...   random.sample(range(1, 2), 3)
... except ValueError:
...   print('Sample size exceeded population size.')
... 
Sample size exceeded population size
```

Comment: Using `random.sample(xrange(1, 100), 3)` - with **xrange** instead of range - speeds the code a lot, particularly if you have a big range, since it will only generate on-demand the required 3 numbers (or more if the sampling without replacement needs it), but not the whole range. For example: `%timeit random.sample(xrange(10000), 3)` = 4.92 µs per loop, `%timeit random.sample(range(10000), 3)` = 126 µs per loop

Comment: If you're using Python2, yes. If you're using Python 3 as in my answer it's already doing this because xrange -> range in Py3k.

Comment: We, could instead of enclosing the `random.sample()` call inside the `try...except` block, check if the size of the sample (`3` above) is smaller or equal (`<=`) than the size of the population (`range(1, 2)` above).

Comment: @h4k1m You can but in general EAFP (try/except) is stylistically preferred to LBYL (if/else) in Python.

Comment: `3` can be replaced with `randint(1, N)`

Comment: This does not apply for float number, to create a list of float sampl = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(50,)) refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071987/generate-random-array-of-floats-between-a-range

Answer (score 33):

Generate the range of data first and then shuffle it like this

```
import random
data = list(range(numLow, numHigh))
random.shuffle(data)
print data
```

By doing this way, you will get all the numbers in the particular range but in a random order.

But you can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to get the number of elements you need, from a range of numbers like this

```
print random.sample(range(numLow, numHigh), 3)
```

Comment: To shuffle a range in python 3 you first need to cast it to a list: `data = list(range(numLow, numHigh))`, otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 16):

You could add to a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) until you reach `n`:

```
setOfNumbers = set()
while len(setOfNumbers) < n:
    setOfNumbers.add(random.randint(numLow, numHigh))
```

Be careful of having a smaller range than will fit in `n`. It will loop forever, unable to find new numbers to insert up to `n`

Comment: If you use `random.sample` it will throw a `ValueError` for that case (which of course you can catch).

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `random.sample` function from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) to select *k* elements from a *population*:

```
import random
random.sample(range(low, high), n)
```

In case of a rather large range of possible numbers, you could use `itertools.islice` with an infinite random generator:

```
import itertools
import random

def random_gen(low, high):
    while True:
        yield random.randrange(low, high)

gen = random_gen(1, 100)
items = list(itertools.islice(gen, 10))  # Take first 10 random elements
```

After the question update it is now clear that you need *n* distinct (unique) numbers.

```
import itertools
import random

def random_gen(low, high):
    while True:
        yield random.randrange(low, high)

gen = random_gen(1, 100)

items = set()

# Try to add elem to set until set length is less than 10
for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: len(items) < 10, gen):
    items.add(x)
```