# PYTHON randomize questions from a list and enumerate

Tags: python, random, enumerate

I have a list of 25 questions that I'd like to randomly select 7. The list of questions will be in an IRC client (Textual). the following is an example of what I currently have as questions and my proposed process of randomizing 7 from my list.

I'd like to make

```
questions=[
    'Finish this poem "Roses are red Violets are ..."',
    'What is your favorite food?','Stones or Beatles?',
    'favorite pet?',
    'favorite color?',
    'favorite food?'
]

for q in xrange(3):
    question = ''
    while question not in questions:
        # this is where I'm stuck
```

I would like something like.

1. What is your favorite food?
2. favorite pet?
3. Stones or Beatles?

The end result will be 7 questions from a pool of 25.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Generate 'n' unique random numbers within a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289/python-generate-n-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range)

Comment: the difference here is I am generating 7 questions in a random order from a list of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shuffle()`:

```
from random import shuffle

shuffle(questions)

for question in questions[:7]:
    answer = input(question)
    # do something with answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.sample()`:

```
import random

for question in random.sample(questions, 7):
    answer = input(question)
```

You need to have enough questions, however.  Right now you have only six questions in the list, so `random.sample()` won't be able to come up with seven random questions.  I'm assuming that your real list has 25 questions since you said `from a pool of 25`, so I merely comment.

Comment: Review your answer. You must be more specific about the use of [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)

Comment: I would be happy to fix it if I see something wrong, but so far I don't see what's wrong with it.  Enlighten me, please.

Comment: Using exactly that way the answer, will provide an error, because `questions` list doesn't have to length enough to choice 7 items

Answer (score 0):

A good approach could be use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample).

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']
>>> selected = []

>>> for item in sample(items, 7):
...    selected.append(item)
>>> print selected
['h', 'l', 'j', 'm', 'i', 'e', 'c']
```