# How do I select a random integer from list, different from previous?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So I have a list with integers like this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And I want to choose random integer from it with choice:

```
item = random.choice(list)
```

But how do I make sure the next time I do this, it is different item? I don't want to remove items from my list.

Comment: You can use `random.sample()`. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289/python-generate-n-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range)

Comment: It's a bit annoying when the question gets closed whilst you're coding a solution. I've posted an answer here if you still need it: https://repl.it/ChS5

Answer (score 2):

If you want *n* different random values from a list, use `random.sample(list, n)`.

Comment: Sorry I sayed this badly, but I need the item to be different every time, not just different from last item

Comment: @mahifoo: I see. What about if you run out of items in the list?

Comment: @Lynn The list has many items and I only need few of them. It won't run out

Comment: ramdom.sample() worked good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need them all anyways and just want them in a random order (but you don't want to change your list), or if you don't have an upper bound on how many items you want to sample (apart from the list size):

```
import random
def random_order(some_list):
    order = list(range(len(some_list)))
    random.shuffle(order)
    for i in order:
        yield some_list[i]

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for item in random_order(my_list):
    ... # do stuff
```

Alternatively, you can use it like this:

```
order = random_order(my_list)
some_item = next(order)
some_item = next(order)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a generator that checks from previous generated choice:

```
import random
def randomNotPrevious(l):
    prev = None
    while True:
        choice =  random.choice(l)
        if choice != prev:
            prev = choice
            yield choice

>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> randomLst = randomNotPrevious(l)
>>> next(randomLst)
1
>>> next(randomLst)
5
>>> next(randomLst)
3
>>> next(randomLst)
6
>>> next(randomLst)
5
```