# How can I make this loop stop at a certain variable occurs

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, random

I need to write a script that generates random numbers between 1-257000 and stops when a certain number occurs telling me how many numbers it generated so far.

i manged to get this far but can't seem to get it to stop or count

```
x=1
while x < 257000:
    import itertools
    import random

    def random_gen(low, high):
        while True:
            yield random.randrange(1, 257000)

    gen = random_gen(1, 100)
    items = list(itertools.islice(gen, 10))

    print items
    x = x+1
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Why are you creating a function in the while loop and repeatedly importing? random_gen takes two arguments that you never use and you  have no break condition so what do you expect to happen, what is the *certain number*?

Comment: I see you just copy/pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/22842533/2141635, you should try to understand code instead of blindly copy/pasting and then getting others to figure the code out for you.

Comment: your while loop break is up to x; if x equals 25700  your loop breaks. so it has not been considered that if certain number generates the loop is over. so you have wait as long as x=25700 and your code stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh. A few flaws (or at least unclear spots) in your code.

1. You run your loop max 257000 times. Even though the probability is low, there is a chance that you don't hit the number you seek in the loop.
2. Move your `import` statements out of your loop, no need to have python check loaded modules each round.
3. You use a generator for choices of a list (`randrange`) where you can simply use a `randint()` call.
4. You define a closed function within your loop which creates a new function at a new memory address each round.
5. You slice your results into lists of 10 elements each; is this for printing, or do you actually need your random integers grouped into such lists?

A very simple and straightforward implementation of your described problem could be:

```
import random
num = 0 # Our counter
certain_number = 123456 # The number we seek

while True: # Run until we break
    # Increment for each new step
    num += 1

    # Generate a single number from the given range
    random_number = random.randint(1, 257000)

    if random_number == certain_number:
        # Break if we hit it
        break

print('Hit after {} tries.'.format(num))

>>> Hit after 382001 tries.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put your `import` statements and your function definitons *outside* your while-loop. That's being **super** redundant.

```
>>> def random_gen(low,high):
...   while True:
...     yield random.randrange(low,high)
... 
>>> lucky = 7
>>> rg = random_gen()   
>>> rg = random_gen(1,1000)                 
>>> next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda t: t[1] != lucky, enumerate(rg, 1)))
(811, 7)
>>>
```

Here's another run, just for fun:

```
>>> rg = random_gen(1,257000)
>>> n,L = next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda t: t[1] != lucky, enumerate(rg, 1)))
>>> n
22602
>>> L
7
>>>
```

Comment: You will need to explain your code as the OP did not really write the code in the question so they will have no idea again what is happening.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Surely, if the OP is using generators then they will understand this code. They wouldn't just blindly copy and paste code and insert it into a while-loop randomly!

Comment: Removing the arguments from `random_gen` will make `rg = random_gen(1,1000)` fail

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that is exactly what they have done, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22842533/2141635 look familiar? There code is not even close to correct, it is a copy/paste jigsaw puzzle that is missing a lot of pieces. They also don't even know where to define functions nor their imports so I am 100 percent confident they have no idea what is happening in your code or their own for that matter.