# Avoid duplicate random values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random

Following [this post](http://sunny.today/generate-random-integers-with-fixed-sum/), I can generate random integers with a fixed sum. However, I want to avoid any duplicate numbers (such as `20` in the following example):

```
import numpy as np

_sum = 100
n = 5
rnd_array = np.random.multinomial(_sum, np.ones(n)/n, size=1)[0]
rnd_array

>>> array([20, 24, 20, 21, 15])
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: The answer is in this link. This question has been answered I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289/generate-n-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range

Comment: @Althaf1467 - In terms of generating random numbers then yes, the post you linked to solves that. But I also want the random values to sum up to a specific value at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.sample` returns a list of unique values ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.sample).) It's called like this:

```
sample = random.sample(range(100), 5)
```

Edit: For using this to get fixed sum, I suggest reading [this thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165044) where the important code is:

```
from random import*
def f(n,s):
  r=min(s,1)
  x=uniform(max(0,r-(r-s/n)*2),r)
  return n<2and[s]or sample([x]+f(n-1,s-x),n)
```

Comment: Your answer solves half the the problem :). The random values generated need to sum to a specific value (in my example, 5 random integers should sum to `100`).

Comment: @Joseph I made an edit to show how `sample` is used in that context

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The float values generated are indeed random and sum to 100. To get it to integer values which I needed, I used `x = int(uniform(max(0, r - (r - s/n) * 2), r))`. Thank you again :)