# How to generate a number of codes with print but without being the same codee?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to generate a number of codes with some random ints but without repeating the same code

I want this source to generate the number of codes that I input but without being the same code, generating them like a list 
currently, when I run the code, it generates one code like this
072546Z73810734AE
but I want  it to generate the number I input for example 3
072546Z73810734AE
072545Z63705472AE
072545Z72904593AE

```
import random
prefix = "07254"
fiveorsix = random.randint(5,6)
letterz = "Z"
sixorseven = random.randint(6,7)
threetwoorone = random.randint(1,3)
sixdigitnumber = random.randint(100000,999999)
lettersae = "AE"
code = 
prefix+str(fiveorsix)+letterz+str(sixorseven)+str(threetwoorone)+
str(sixdigitnumber)+lettersae
print(code)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate 'n' unique random numbers within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289/generate-n-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your code:

```
for i in range(3):
    prefix = "07254"
    fiveorsix = random.randint(5,6)
    letterz = "Z"
    sixorseven = random.randint(6,7)
    threetwoorone = random.randint(1,3)
    sixdigitnumber = random.randint(100000,999999)
    lettersae = "AE"
    code = prefix+str(fiveorsix)+letterz+str(sixorseven)+str(threetwoorone)+str(sixdigitnumber)+lettersae

    print(code)
```

If you want to be able to define a number, do the same inside a function:

```
def create_codes(n):

    for i in range(n):
        prefix = "07254"
        fiveorsix = random.randint(5,6)
        letterz = "Z"
        sixorseven = random.randint(6,7)
        threetwoorone = random.randint(1,3)
        sixdigitnumber = random.randint(100000,999999)
        lettersae = "AE"
        code = prefix+str(fiveorsix)+letterz+str(sixorseven)+str(threetwoorone)+str(sixdigitnumber)+lettersae

        print(code)
```

Output of `create_codes(3)`:

```
072545Z71278632AE
072545Z62372104AE
072546Z72750938AE
```