# I cannot take multiple values in rand.randrange with k?

Tags: python, random

Is there any way to take multiple values with "random.randrange"? Like in random.choices or random.sample we can choose more than 1 element with "k".

```
import random
print("3 values divided by 3")
print(random.randrange(100,999,5,k=3,end=','))
```

Comment: Related: [Generate 'n' unique random numbers within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22842289/4518341), [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755538/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't specific functions to do this in the `random` module, but look at the docs for [`randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

> This is equivalent to `choice(range(start, stop, step))`, but doesn't actually build a range object.

Therefore, just do `choices(range(...), k=3)` or `sample(range(...), k=3)`.

Note: In Python 3, this will be memory-efficient since `range` is lazy. In Python 2, I believe [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) behaves the same.