# Unique Number Generator in Python

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to make a number generator for a project I am working on, and I need every number to be unique. The range is '0-100000'. I have the following:

```
    for i in range (1,100000):
        num = random.randint(0, 100000)
        store = num
        print (num)
        num = random.randint(0, 100000)
        if num == store:
            num = '-'
        print(num)
```

I can't go through all the outputs in a timely manner, but at a glance, I have seen two issues with them. Firstly, there are repeats, because 'store' gets changed every time, and is only one number. Secondly, one of the outputs, on my current output screen, is '4183053688'. The range doesn't allow for that, so I don't know what happened.

I have only thought of two possible answers. Firstly I have played around with making a list to check whether a number has been used or not, but I haven't found a way to update it as numbers come in, and I will be using so many number in a short time, that manually putting them in is impractical. My second idea is what the code shows. But those problems have already been explained.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22842289/2442804

Comment: What's the problem with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. Those are unique. Or it must be random too?

Comment: @luk2302 I just tried that, and it did not work. No outputs happened.

Comment: @simre Yes, randomization is necessary

Comment: Then I think you should check `set` in python. You can just push random numbers in it until you get the required number of numbers. In a set you cannot have duplicates so it'll insert or do nothing if it's there already. Not the most effective way but really simple

Comment: The answers there are perfect duplicates, there is nothing more to do than use one of them.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many numbers you need ?

Comment: @luk2302 What do you mean?

Comment: @simre I tried that, but I am incredibly bad at programming, so do you mind explaining it?

Comment: I mean what I said: the linked question and its answers perfectly answers this question and anything that is posted here will just be a duplicate / repetition of what has already been posted there.

Comment: @NoéDuruz As many as possible. I will be using a lot.

Comment: @luk2302 It does not work though? I tried what the link led me to, and the program did not output anything. Not even an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755538/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-random-numbers-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

random.sample with range specified does the job for your [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#:%7E:text=random.sample(population%2C%20k%2C%20*%2C%20counts%3DNone))

```
import random
unique_numbers = random.sample(range(0, 100001),100000)
print(unique_numbers)
```

Comment: If you're sampling the entire range why not just build a list and shuffle it?

Answer (score 0):

So what you're saying is that you want all the numbers in a range returned in a random order. Therefore:

```
from random import shuffle

def func(r: range) -> list[int]:
    _list: list[int] = list(r)
    shuffle(_list)
    return _list

print(func(range(100_000)))
```

**Note:**

This will return a list comprised of **all** values in the range. If you don't need the full list then just slice it

Comment: So. I am extremely bad at programming, so could you possibly explain what this does?

Comment: @BrendanCarey It makes a list from a range then pseudo-randomly rearranges that list (shuffle) and returns it

Comment: Got it...I think. Thanks for the help. Apologies for taking your time with a beginner question.

Answer (score 0):

You asked me to explain the "set" solution to this problem in comment. So this is a possible solution:

```
s = set()
while len(s) < 100:
    s.add(random.randint(0, 1000))
```

A set is an unordered collection without duplicates, so you cannot add the same number multiple times.

The code above add random numbers to the set called s until its length reaches your target length. But you must be sure to request less or equal numbers than the input range of the randint function or you will run into an infinite loop. Also avoid to request roughly the same length of the input range or you will simply get [0, 1, 2, 3, ...] which will be a unique list but not really random...

In performance it is not the best. Up to a few hundred thousand elements it can finish in a fraction of a second. But as you increase the required random numbers your runtime will explode.