# How to set random values to 2d-numpy-array where values are very low?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d-numpy-array (28x28) and would like to set random values to all that indices which have a value lower than 50. I tried something:

```
myarray[myarray < 50] = random.randint(80,100)
```

This doesn't work correctly because all selected indices are getting the same random value. 
I would like to have different random values.

```
for y in range(28):
   for x in range(28):
      if myarray[y,x] < 50:
         myarray[y,x] = random.randint(80,100)
```

The code above is solving the problem, but I think that it doesn't work efficently, because it gets very slow with big datasets.

Is there any better function?

Comment: You can create random arrays of a specified size e.g numpy.random.randint(80,100,(3,2)) would create array of shape [3,2] , so just create a random array the size of myarray<50, and put that instead 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Answer (score 1):

First, use `np.random.uniform` instead. See [Generate random array of floats between a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071987/generate-random-array-of-floats-between-a-range)

Then,

```
myarray[myarray < 50] = np.random.uniform(low=80, high=100,
       size=myarray[myarray < 50].shape)
```